# ArcGIS field calculator pythons script value transfer between columns

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, attribute-table, python-parser

In the picture below I can transfer values from one field(FID) to another(Id) using ArcGIS. The issue is that I will end up with some duplicated values in field "Id" (example number 12 and 17).

My question is how to add to the script a function that removes or prevent duplicateted values? (elif?)

Script so far is:

```
def reclass(a,y ): 
    if a == 0: 
       a = y
    else:
       pass
    return a

IDV2 = reclass( !Id!, !FID! )
```

[image]

Comment: I dont understand your question. Duplicates in what column? Could you give an example

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  Your question isn't clear - What exactly are you trying to do?  Please [edit] your question to tell us which field you want to populate using the field calculator, which field you want to copy the values from, and what duplicates you are referring to.  Is your column blank, or does it already contain data you need to filter somehow?